# How to return an array from a postgres select query?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that holds scenario information and whether or not it is active and I query the scenario like so

```
SELECT 
scenario.*, 
scenario_detail.name,
scenario_detail.is_activated,
scenario_detail.is_current,
scenario_detail.input_values,
scenario_detail.scenario_id,
scenario_detail.user_id,
scenario_detail.plan_id,
scenario_detail.order_index
FROM scenario 
INNER join scenario_detail 
ON scenario_detail.scenario_id = scenario.id
WHERE scenario_detail.state = 'ACTIVE'
```

And it returns the scenarios fine.
Now I would like to return an array that will have two items, a list of all activated scenario and another of inactive scenarios.

I know I could slice and sort these scenarios in the front end but I am rather interested in doing it in the backend.

How could I do it?

Comment: Could you include how your desired result should look like? Do you want that query to return 2 columns, that would be arrays of rows each? I doubt that your backend would handle that but to me it sounds like you are asking for this.

Answer (score 0):

If all the fields are same then you can use union.

```
SELECT 
scenario.*, 
scenario_detail.name,
scenario_detail.is_activated,
scenario_detail.is_current,
scenario_detail.input_values,
scenario_detail.scenario_id,
scenario_detail.user_id,
scenario_detail.plan_id,
scenario_detail.order_index
FROM scenario 
INNER join scenario_detail 
ON scenario_detail.scenario_id = scenario.id
WHERE scenario_detail.state = 'ACTIVE'
UNION 
SELECT 
scenario.*, 
scenario_detail.name,
scenario_detail.is_activated,
scenario_detail.is_current,
scenario_detail.input_values,
scenario_detail.scenario_id,
scenario_detail.user_id,
scenario_detail.plan_id,
scenario_detail.order_index
FROM scenario 
INNER join scenario_detail 
ON scenario_detail.scenario_id = scenario.id
WHERE scenario_detail.state = 'INACTIVE'
```